# How to delete a user's custom claims firebase cloud functions

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I want to delete firebase user custom claims and reset user claims as default, im tried to set null to claims.

i want claims return undefined as default

[default claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH5sy.png)

[after deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aILYk.png)

code 1:.

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRecord.uid, null).then(() => {
                // See the contents of userRecord.
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error delete staff claim" + error.message);
            });
```

code 2:.

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRecord.uid, {}).then(() => {
                // See the contents of userRecord.
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error delete staff claim" + error.message);
            });
```

Comment: And the error message was what?

Comment: Don't post pictures of textual content please. Instead include the actual text, and use the formatting toolbar to mark it up correctly.